# how to make this image in Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how to make this image in bootstrap 3....
i will can  view this image in mobile view in to three seperate rows and desktop in to one row.
in mobile view each row contains one part of image..
please help me..

```
<section class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 padding-0">

                <img src="/images/chatti.png" alt="5" >

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 padding-0">

                <img src="/images/sofa.png" alt="5" >

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 padding-0">

                <img src="/images/slider.png" alt="5" >

        </div>


    </div>
    </section>
```

[image]
this is a psd imge file....

Answer (score 0):

To view images in a single row in mobile, you have to write bootstrap classes as below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
            <img src="/images/chatti.png" alt="5" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
            <img src="/images/sofa.png" alt="5" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 padding-0">
            <img src="/images/slider.png" alt="5" >
    </div>
</div>
```

col-sm is for tablets and col-xs for mobiles

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display the images as a single image in smaller screen size as well? If yes then the code should be like

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 padding-0">
                <img src="/images/chatti.png" alt="5" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 padding-0">
                <img src="/images/sofa.png" alt="5" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 padding-0">
                <img src="/images/slider.png" alt="5" >
        </div>
</div>
```

You need not add the "col-md-4" or "col-lg-4" class, as bootstrap uses the same width from smaller screens if higher screen size are not mentioned.

Comment: iam trying to display the images as three images in smaller screen size and one image in larger screen size

Comment: @kasim521 Use only `col-md-4` class then. That way screen size bigger than tablet will display the images in a single row, where as for mobile and tablet, it will fall back to full width like using class `col-xs-12` and `col-sm-12`.